# Save an Excel file into Local Directory using c#

Tags: c#, export

I am creating an Excel using `EPPlus` and `Datatable`.Now as per my requirement i have to save this into my local system directory but i am not able to get how to achieve this ..
The path where i have to save is `C://Reports//excel.xls`

Here is my code

```
 using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
   {
     ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(reportName);
     ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(DT, true);
     pck.Save();
   }
```

Please help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Reports\excel.xls");

if (newFile.Exists)
{
    newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
    newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Reports\excel.xls");
}

using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
     ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(reportName);
     ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(DT, true);
     pck.Save();
}
```

Comment: The best overloaded method had invalid argument errro at `ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile)`